# How to Add Custom Functions for Permutations and Combinations in Dart with math_expressions?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have been working on a Dart program that involves calculating permutations (nPr) and combinations (nCr) using the math_expressions library. However, I am having difficulty adding custom functions for nPr and nCr to the existing code.

Here's the code I have so far:

```
void main() {
  myExample('5P2');
}

void myExample(String inputString) {
  Parser p = Parser();
  
  Expression exp = p.parse(inputString);

  Variable e = Variable('exp');
  Variable pi = Variable('Pi');
  Variable n = Variable('n');
  Variable r = Variable('r');

  

  ContextModel cm = ContextModel()
    ..bindVariable(e, Number(math.e))
    ..bindVariable(pi, Number(math.pi));

  double eval = exp.evaluate(EvaluationType.REAL, cm);

  print(eval);
}
```

What I would like to do is add custom functions for nPr and nCr, so I can use these functions directly in the inputString.

Could you please guide me on how to add the custom functions to this code?

i tried to add this customFunction,

CustomFunction solvePerms =
CustomFunction('perms', [n, r], Factorial(n) / Factorial(n - r));